# Ошибка использования указателей

Tags: c, c++

Почему при компиляции кода:

```
char *first, second;

second = first;
```

возникает предупреждение:

```
*warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по строке

```
first = second;
```

необходимо определить два указателя и присвоить значение одного из них другому. В C определение вида

```
char *pointer;
```

задает указатель на char, а определение вида

```
char variable;
```

задает переменную типа char. Чтобы определить два указателя на char нужно изменить код.

```
char *first, *second;

first = second;
```